# How to change the default font of TinyMCE for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I see this question on SO but all answers fail to be specific on how to change that.

What I mean is this: the answers say "add this" but they fail to tell where, I mean, which file and one has to be a rocket scientist to figure that out.

Can someone explain **like I am five**, ok, make it 3... all steps I have to do to get rid of the infamous Libre Franklin font and put Helvetica as the default on TinyMCE editor for wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-change-default-font/) gives pretty clear instructions.

1) Add a new css file, called it whatever you want, like `tinymce_custom_editor.css` for example, upload it to the folder "css" in your theme -> `wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/css/`

2) Add a new function in your theme `function.php` file:

## The CSS

Make a file `tinymce_custom_editor.css` with following code ↓, then add it to folder `wp-content/themes/grandblog/css`

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
```

## The Function

Add following new function to call previously uploaded css file `tinymce_custom_editor.css` in `wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/functions.php` ↓

```
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'css/tinymce_custom_editor.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: thanks. I am trying this but the editor is not changing.... the dropdown always shows Libre Franklin, 20 px. as default

Comment: Found the problem. I copied from here and pasted on functions.php but the apostrophe used here is not the normal one is a fancy one... replacing it with a normal one did the trick! THANKS, you are a genius!

Comment: Lol, not really.  I just know how to Google :)