# How to set the font-family as specified when editing post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, font-family

I have created a  child themes, set font-family as my desired `DejaVu Sans Mono` for every html element.

```
vim /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/style.css
*{
    font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono" !important;
}
```

I use `twentyfourteen-child` as my wordpress theme.
Every character in edit status is not  `DejaVu Sans Mono`.
[image]

Every character in post is  `DejaVu Sans Mono`  after published.
[image]

How can i set the font-family as `DejaVu Sans Mono`  when editing post?

Comment: You are changing the frontend css file which wont reflect in wp-admin end css even if you specify !important property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the default font of TinyMCE for Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619233/how-to-change-the-default-font-of-tinymce-for-wordpress)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use your browser developer tools, to see the actual file for the stylesheet.
You only edited the stylesheet for the theme - so only applying to the frontend of your website!

On my wordpress system I got the url for the stylesheet you need. It is:

```
your.site.com/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css
```

There you can possibly find something like

```
.wp-editor-area {
    font-family: Consolas,Monaco,monospace;
}
```

Change that to

```
.wp-editor-area {
    font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono" !important;
}
```

If you want to change the styles for the backend you can also have a look at the stylesheets in /wp-includes/ and /wp-admin/ .

Please keep in mind, that those changes are back to normal after any updates.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is **simple solution to change editor styles** . Add this in `functions.php`:

```
function myFunc123( $settings ) {
    $settings['content_style'] .= 'body#tinymce {font-family: DejaVu Sans Mono;}'; return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myFunc123' );
```